ps command is stuck forever reading `/proc/*/environ`
I'm trying to use Rustrover, but it is pretty unstable, and whenever it crashes or is stuck and killed by me, ps command and any other task managers get stuck forever before showing anything. Following advice from other threads, I ran strace ps, but I don't know what to do next. Here are last lines:
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4282/status", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Name:\tspotify\nUmask:\t0022\nState:"..., 2048) = 1169
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4282/environ", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "=pl --user-data-dir=/home/michal"..., 131072) = 1839
read(4, "", 129233)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4282/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "/opt/spotify/spotify --type=util"..., 131072) = 477
read(4, "", 130595)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4282/ctty", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4287", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4287/stat", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "4287 (spotify) S 4229 1707 1707 "..., 2048) = 285
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4287/status", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Name:\tspotify\nUmask:\t0022\nState:"..., 2048) = 1170
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4287/environ", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Cache\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 131072) = 1870
read(4, "", 129202)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4287/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "/opt/spotify/spotify --type=util"..., 131072) = 474
read(4, "", 130598)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4287/ctty", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4308", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4308/stat", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "4308 (spotify) S 4234 1707 1707 "..., 2048) = 295
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4308/status", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Name:\tspotify\nUmask:\t0022\nState:"..., 2048) = 1178
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4308/environ", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "sandbox --log-file=/opt/spotify/"..., 131072) = 1839
read(4, "", 129233)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4308/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "/opt/spotify/spotify --type=rend"..., 131072) = 597
read(4, "", 130475)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/4308/ctty", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/5138", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/5138/stat", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "5138 (rustc) D 1542 1707 1707 0 "..., 2048) = 306
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/5138/status", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Name:\trustc\nUmask:\t0022\nState:\tD"..., 2048) = 1169
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/5138/environ", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, 

and content of /proc/5138/status:
Name:        rustc
Umask:  0022
State:  D (disk sleep)
Tgid:   5138
Ngid:   0
Pid:    5138
PPid:   1542
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Gid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
FDSize: 128
Groups: 90 98 959 984 987 991 994 996 998 1000 
NStgid: 5138
NSpid:  5138
NSpgid: 1707
NSsid:  1707
VmPeak:   236164 kB
VmSize:   236164 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     29020 kB
VmRSS:     29020 kB
RssAnon:           11096 kB
RssFile:           17924 kB
RssShmem:              0 kB
VmData:    11196 kB
VmStk:       132 kB
VmExe:       352 kB
VmLib:    158980 kB
VmPTE:       196 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
HugetlbPages:          0 kB
CoreDumping:    0
THP_enabled:    1
Threads:        1
SigQ:   6/127234
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000004
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
SigCgt: 0000000000000440
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 000001ffffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
NoNewPrivs:     0
Seccomp:        0
Seccomp_filters:        0
Speculation_Store_Bypass:       thread vulnerable
SpeculationIndirectBranch:      conditional enabled
Cpus_allowed:   ffffff
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-23
Mems_allowed:   00000001
Mems_allowed_list:      0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:        1
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     13

cat /proc/5138/environ hangs forever. Any idea what is happening and how to fix it?
[Edit]
This time the same problem with Java.
strace ps:
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151969/environ", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Brak dostępu)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151969/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "", 131072)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151969/ctty", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151970", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151970/stat", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "151970 (kworker/9:1-events) I 2 "..., 2048) = 172
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151970/status", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Name:\tkworker/9:1-events\nUmask:\t"..., 2048) = 758
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151970/environ", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Brak dostępu)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151970/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "", 131072)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151970/ctty", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151971", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151971/stat", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "151971 (kworker/5:2) I 2 0 0 0 -"..., 2048) = 165
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151971/status", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Name:\tkworker/5:2\nUmask:\t0000\nSt"..., 2048) = 749
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151971/environ", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Brak dostępu)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151971/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "", 131072)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/151971/ctty", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/152058", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/152058/stat", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "152058 (kworker/0:1) I 2 0 0 0 -"..., 2048) = 165
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/152058/status", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Name:\tkworker/0:1\nUmask:\t0000\nSt"..., 2048) = 749
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/152058/environ", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Brak dostępu)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/152058/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "", 131072)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/152058/ctty", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/152089", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/152089/stat", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "152089 (java) S 1663 1663 1663 0"..., 2048) = 339
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/152089/status", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "Name:\tjava\nUmask:\t0022\nState:\tS "..., 2048) = 1177
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/152089/environ", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, 


cat /proc/152089/status:
Name:   java
Umask:  0022
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   152089
Ngid:   0
Pid:    152089
PPid:   1663
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Gid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
FDSize: 256
Groups: 90 98 959 984 987 991 994 996 998 1000 
NStgid: 152089
NSpid:  152089
NSpgid: 1663
NSsid:  1663
VmPeak: 20889548 kB
VmSize: 20889548 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:   1406604 kB
VmRSS:   1406604 kB
RssAnon:     1079756 kB
RssFile:      326716 kB
RssShmem:        132 kB
VmData:  1448488 kB
VmStk:       140 kB
VmExe:         4 kB
VmLib:     41436 kB
VmPTE:      5404 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
HugetlbPages:          0 kB
CoreDumping:    0
THP_enabled:    1
Threads:    234
SigQ:   3/127234
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000001000
SigCgt: 2000000101004cef
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 000001ffffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
NoNewPrivs: 0
Seccomp:    0
Seccomp_filters:    0
Speculation_Store_Bypass:   thread vulnerable
SpeculationIndirectBranch:  conditional enabled
Cpus_allowed:   ffffff
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-23
Mems_allowed:   00000001
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    38
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 12


cat /proc/152089/environ hangs. sudo cat /proc/152089/stack:
[<0>] futex_wait_queue+0x63/0x90
[<0>] futex_wait+0x189/0x270
[<0>] do_futex+0xc6/0x190
[<0>] __x64_sys_futex+0x129/0x1e0
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x5d/0x90
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x64/0xce

dmesg: https://pastebin.com/Uy1kjZrX
It looks like some multithreading problem, but I have no idea what to do with it.

What does the output of /proc/<pid>/stack show? If the process is in a syscall which is blocked that might reveal some information. E.g. while developing a Linux Kernel module I had a bug in the Kernel module code in trying to take a mutex, such that when the user space process tried an ioctl on the Kernel module that caused the user process to hang, and had similar behaviour in that trying to use ps got stuck. The contents of the stack file identified the cause of the issue.

I'll add stack when the issue happens again, may take some time.

A further thought is that a Kernel call trace may be generated when the issues occurs - see Understanding a dmesg kernel warning message for an example output. dmesg can be used to look for such call trace messages for the current boot. If call trace had been generated in previous boots, try searching the /var/log/messages file (or equivalent) for your Linux distribution.

Problem replicated, still no idea how to handle it.

Looking at information haven't identified the root cause. Looking at the dmesg output noticed that the system has entered system sleep state S3 and woken up from that sleep state twice in total. Do you know if the failure only occurs after the system has entered sleep and then woken up?
